# simple join with null values

Tags: sql, database, tags

this is a simple one, but for some reason i just can't crack it and my brain has given up

it's about populating a handful of checkboxes with some of them checked according to a lookup

i've got three tables: tags, items, and a junction table called itemtags. i have the 'item_id' as the identifier for the query

### tags

- tag_id (pk)
- tag

and a junction table

### itemtags

- tag_id  (fk from tags)
- item_id (fk from items

(item_id is the pk from the items table and i always have this value, so it's not necessary for this question)

the checkboxes are populated from the tags table.

i want to run a query using the item_id as an identifier, which gets all the tags and returns them (there are only 5) and checks them according to item_id, so there will always be 5 rows.

the 'item_id' returned on each tag will therefore sometimes be null (which means an unchecked checkbox in this case)

i'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but i just can't see it

tia

Comment: I don't quite understand, you want _all_ tags listed, with a column telling if they're checked or not for that item? Could you give an example of your desired input/output?

Answer (score 0):

This'll list all tags, and whether they're checked or not for a specific item;

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN item_id IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END checked_for_item_1
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN itemtags
  ON tags.tag_id = itemtags.tag_id
 AND item_id = 1 
ORDER BY tags.tag_id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6c1f/4).